# Verify if test case body or teardown fails in teardown

Tags: robotframework

We use `${TEST_STATUS}` variable to determine in test teardown section if some keyword fails in test body. Based on the value we either collect or not logs from SUT.

However, if some keyword fails in test teardown section just before verification of `${TEST_STATUS}` and test body passes, the value of the variable does not reflect that.

Is it possible to check if any keyword fails in test body, setup and teardown, and based on that perform some logic in teardown? Or any other suggestions?

Comment: Though I myself cannot help you in solving this issue, I would suggest [filing an issue for it](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues) - the current behavior doesn't sound right; as failing teardown fails otherwise passing case, I can't think of a reason the automatic variable not to reflect that.

Comment: @TodorMinakov, thanks. Looks to be known issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an [issue](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/2078) in Robot Framework Github. As per discussion, it is hard to fix and requires huge amount of efforts. If someone is interested in fixing, Robotframework community suggests to sponsor this from 3rd party end.

So far work-arounds are unclear.